# Twitter Sharer URL - Adding an #anchor to the end of a URL

Tags: twitter, share

I am trying to create a sharer url suitable for Twitter.

I have posted the URL string with the # attached

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Check%20out%20this%20property%20on%201st%20Degree%20http://localhost/1st-degree.co.uk/properties-rooms#11-myrtle-street

But when I go to post to Twitter the #11-myrtyle-street hash is removed from the sharer URL.

As per this screenshot

[image: Twitter Sharer URL]

Can anyone help me get this anchor appended to the URL, If at all possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to urlencode that hashtag.
With %23 it's working.

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Check%20out%20this%20property%20on%201st%20Degree%20http://localhost/1st-degree.co.uk/properties-rooms%2311-myrtle-street